# What is the most effective method for adding nested data to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to add the JSON data from this [API](https://api.covid19api.com/summary) to a pandas data frame. Here is the code I have tried:

```
url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary'
df = pd.read_json(url)

print(df.head())
```

When running this code, I receive the following error:

> ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous
>   ordering.

Any advice on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Matt and welcome on SO. Whenever you work with `json` it's better to first get the data and have a look at it. In your particular case the key `Global` is different from the ones in `Countries` that's why you get that error

```py
import urllib.request
import json
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
# the following is the data you should explore
data = json.loads(response.read())

df = pd.DataFrame(data["Countries"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON has a couple of elements ('Global', 'Countries' and 'Date'), so it would make sense to split it up into separate dataframes, which is not easy to do using `pandas.read_json()`.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
global_data = pd.DataFrame(data['Global'])
countries = pd.DataFrame(data['Countries'])
```